# System has not been booted with systemd as init system (PID 1). Can't operate. Failed to connect to bus: Host is down

Tags: google-cloud-platform, systemd

I am trying to activate service after creating a systemd service using the following commands in google cloud terminal:

```
vim /etc/systemd/system/app.service
```

Pasted the contents below to this file:

```
#vim /etc/systemd/system/app.service
[Unit]
#  specifies metadata and dependencies
Description=Gunicorn instance to serve myproject
After=network.target
# tells the init system to only start this after the networking target has been reached
# We will give our regular user account ownership of the process since it owns all of the relevant files
[Service]
# Service specify the user and group under which our process will run.
User=clashgamers2021
# give group ownership to the www-data group so that Nginx can communicate easily with the Gunicorn processes.
Group=www-data
# We'll then map out the working directory and set the PATH environmental variable so that the init system knows where our the executables for the process are located (wi$
WorkingDirectory=/home/clashgamers2021/clashgamers/
Environment="PATH=/home/clashgamers2021/clashgamers/env/bin"
# We'll then specify the commanded to start the service
ExecStart=/home/clashgamers2021/clashgamers/env/bin/gunicorn --workers 3 --bind unix:app.sock -m 007 wsgi:app
# This will tell systemd what to link this service to if we enable it to start at boot. We want this service to start when the regular multi-user system is up and running:
[Install]
WantedBy=multi-user.target
```

For activating this service, I typed:

```
sudo systemctl start app
sudo systemctl enable app
```

However I got this error:

```
clashgamers2021@cloudshell:~/clashgamers (clash-gamers-318206)$ sudo systemctl start app
System has not been booted with systemd as init system (PID 1). Can't operate.
Failed to connect to bus: Host is down
```

Comment: Hi there! You mentioned that you ran this code  in```google cloud terminal```, where specifically ? Inside a VM or inside Google Cloud Shell? What type of VM are you running (N1, E2, etc) with what OS (Red Hat, Rocky, COS, etc)?

Comment: Based on the error message, are you sure your OS version has systemd service installed? Confirm that first and one thing I did not see you in your original post, make sure you reload systemd daemon after adding a new service: systemctl daemon-reload

Answer (score 1):

You're trying to run the commands in the [Cloud Shell](https://cloud.google.com/shell/docs):

> Cloud Shell is an interactive shell environment for Google Cloud that makes it easy for you to learn and experiment with Google Cloud and manage your projects and resources from your web browser.

[Create a new VM](https://cloud.google.com/compute/docs/instances/create-start-instance) (specify hardware & OS) and connect to it using [SSH button](https://cloud.google.com/compute/docs/instances/connecting-to-instance#connecting_to_vms) in the Cloud Console or use other methods described in the documentation.

Then run your commands and if they don't work update your question with more details.